# Angular- service providing components (TS error)

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm making my first try to inject dynamically components. So far I'm pretty successful for now, but I have an error coming from Typescript which is bugging me (don't like have errors in my code)

Here is the link to the app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vrtr51?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.ts

My goal was to have a service capable of providing me any component I need, to inject it from anywhere (for a widget based website).

But I have this error message in the console: 
error TS2339: Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.

You can see it in app.component.ts at line 35

Code however is working fine, but I would like to understand why this error message.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.compProvider.get('header'));
```

If you look at `factory`'s type, it is `ComponentFactory<{}>`. This is because you're getting the component type using your service which returns a type of any.

```
export class ComponentProviderService {
  public get(id): any {
    console.log(this.componentMap[id]);
    return this.componentMap[id];
  }
}
```

When you do the following on line 30, you're creating the component using `factory`'s type, which is implicitly `ComponentFactory<{}>` because of that service returning `any`.

```
const comRef = this.headerContainer.createComponent(factory);
```

Therefore, `comRef` ends up being of type `ComponentRef<{}>`, which has the property `instance`, but `instance`'s type is `{}`, which is the part giving you the error: `Property 'data' does not exist on type '{}'.`

If you replace line 29 with

```
const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(HeaderComponent);
```

It now works as you expect, without the error, because the type of `factory` is now explicitly `ComponentFactory<HeaderComponent>`, which in turn means `comRef` is of type `ComponentRef<HeaderComponent>`, which in turn means the property `instance` is now of type `HeaderComponent`.

Comment: OK thank you, I understand now! The problem I have with your solution is I have to import all the components I need to inject in the app component, what I'm trying to avoid. So to keep my service which will return lots of different components, I've just declared the ComponentRef's instance as any:
const comRef: ComponentRef<any> = this.headerContainer.createComponent( factory );
As I can't type it with the type of the component I will return, I think any is the only type possible here.

Comment: @Projeer I wasn't saying you should directly use `HeaderComponent` as your solution. Your question was simply "I would like to understand why this error message." I was just explaining that, if you were to use `HeaderComponent` instead, you wouldn't see the error anymore. But yea, explicitly declaring those `factory` and `comRef` variables you have as `ComponentFactory<any>` or `ComponentRef<any>` respectively would also get rid of the issue. The trade off is you lose those strongly typed properties, but this is probably the only way to do what your doing using your service returning `any`.